# Как получить цвет пикселя виджета  QT?

Tags: qt, c++

Нужно получить значание RGB именно одной точки на QWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую, Олег.
Вы все по старому проекту пилите или уже закрыли его и взяли новый? :)

В общем, тебе надо сначала в QPixmap преобразование сделать, смотри метод grabWidget http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html 
Уже из QPixmap можно получить цвет конкретной точки.

Comment: Так оно и есть, все равно сам разобрался, выложу попозже рабочий код, чтобы хоть вопрос не зря был задан, ваш ответ помучу как лучший, спасибо пилю все тот же, в QT это вторая моя программа